# Is it possible to shrink a page using something like \enlargethispage?

Tags: margins

This seems like a silly question to have to ask, but I can't find information on it anywhere. I know that `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}` can be used to add an extra line to a page in order to help deal with page layout problems. But how can you run a page one line *short*? Using a value like `-1\baselineskip` doesn't work (negative values seem to have some special meaning, though I'm not entirely clear on what it is).

Comment: You should really try it to see...

Comment: It ought to work with negative values. Maybe just one line is not enough, because TeX tries to avoid club or widow lines.

Comment: @Werner: Sorry, maybe I worded it confusingly. I *did* try putting a negative value in, and it didn't work, so I'm wondering if there's a different command or option that I need to use.

Comment: A nice answer would be to increase the margins of just one page. See this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44439837/2961878

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can enlarge the page (goal) by a negative value:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\enlargethispage{-\baselineskip}%
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

It's clear that there's a missing line (`\baselineskip`) on the first page as a result of `\enlargethispage{-\baselineskip}`.

<sub>Note that certain things (document classes or perhaps calls to macros) may cause or allow for spreading of content vertically in such a way that it's not really noticeable on the page where you might be experiencing a problem.

Moreover, in certain special cases this might not work as expected, as TeX may place a larger penalty on certain layouts (like widows/clubs).</sub>

Comment: Thanks – the edit is helpful since it clarifies why the problem was happening in the first place. I've deleted my own answer, as it's less thorough and redundant with this one.